# Как создать посредника для обработки команд?

Tags: c#

Реализую паттерн CQRS и задался вопросом того как реализовать посредника для исполнения команд, у меня есть интерфейс ICommand, который помечает, что данный объект это команда

```
public interface ICommand
{

}
```

И есть hanlder для этой команды

И есть интерфейс, который обрабатывает эту команду

```
public interface ICommandHandler<in TCommand> where TCommand : ICommand
{
    Task HandleAsync(TCommand command, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
}

public interface ICommandHandler<in TCommand, TResult> where TCommand : ICommand
{
    Task<TResult> HandleAsync(TCommand command, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
}
```

И как для этого можно создать промежуточный объект, который будет принимать команду и будет знать какой обработчик ему вызвать?

UPD. пока сделал так:
public class CommandDispatcher : ICommandDispatcher
{
private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

```
    public CommandDispatcher(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider ??
                           throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(serviceProvider));
    }

    public Task ExecuteAsync<TCommand>(TCommand command, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default) where TCommand : ICommand
    {
        var handler = _serviceProvider.GetService<ICommandHandler<TCommand>>();

        if(handler == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(handler));
        
        return handler.HandleAsync(command, cancellationToken);
    }

    public Task<TResult> ExecuteAsync<TCommand, TResult>(TCommand command, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        where TCommand : ICommand
    {
        var handler = _serviceProvider.GetService<ICommandHandler<TCommand, TResult>>();

        if (handler == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(handler));

        return handler.HandleAsync(command, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Comment: Если у вас DI контейнер, то его и используйте. То есть для команды типа `T` можно резолвить обработчик `ICommandHandler<T>`

Comment: Интерфейс без членов называется маркерным. Такие интерфейсы не рекомендуются к применению в дотнете (вместо них следует использовать атрибуты). | Зачем вообще нужен какой-то посредник? Почему бы не сделать интерфейс с методом Invoke (или Process; короче, дайте ему говорящее название). Для команды, которая может возвращать значение, сделайте другой метод.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, а не могли бы вы подробнее расписать решение, пожалуйста